# NSXML Parsing through objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser, nsxml

I am working on xml parsing through Objective C. I am getting trouble into following part.
Please help me out. I am using `NSXMLParser` class and its delegates.

How to trace out "url", "type", "height" these tags from below XML code.

```
<image url="http://d.img.com/a/r/rids/20110203/i/r32323.jpg?
x=130&amp;y=91&amp;q=85&amp;sig=bJdeYbrqFsYUuZJ.fFwa8g--"  
type="image/jpeg"  height="91" width="130"/>
```

Comment: d.img.com resolves as an unknown host from here; is there anywhere else the linked image can be seen?

Comment: Did you forget to include your XML code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement delegate function

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

and inside it

```
NSLog(@"url: %@", [attributeDict valueForKey:@"url"]);
```

etc.